# How to bulk import multi-language data to channel entries?

Tags: channel-entries, database, multi-language, datagrab, import

I'm trying to import a data base that has multi-language entries to EE and thought of using [DataGrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab). I'm using [Publisher](http://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher) plugin to relate multi-language entries. Is there a way that I can import the DB without losing the relation between entries and their translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'relationship' is the entry_id. So if you can import the default language, grab the entry id, then import the translated entry and assign the same entry_id it should work. I'm not sure DataGrab would do that out of the box.